# Logo background colour looks different on mobile vs web

Tags: html, css

I have a logo with a blue background, I've picked the colour via Chrome inspector (matches Firefox colour picker as well), yet on mobile the logo stands out on the background.

[image]

What's going on/how can I prevent this?

Comment: `How can I prevent this`, use a transparent image with just the text.

Comment: That's a good point, is there a good online tool to do that? I don't have photoshop

Comment: Using The Gimp?!

Comment: I wouldn't know, im not a designer ;p

Comment: Looks like it can be done in preview lol http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-use-previews-instant-alpha-magic-wand-tool-in-os-x/ , okay I agree that's the solution thanks (couldn't think of that solution for some reason, prob cuz I'm not a designer either lol))

Answer (score 3):

**Why you see another color on another display?**

That logo has at least 5 colors in the background. That's the reason you can not match it.

Your monitor and mobile displays are not accurate, and it seems your contrast and brightness of the screen are not correct. In the professional photography and video editing, they call it *color blind*.

That's the reason professional designers do not use consumer monitors.

If you are a designer you need to have color accurate monitor and you need to calibrate it.

If you want to keep working on the current monitor at least change your monitor brightness, contrast and color settings, close to the natural settings.

**What is the software solution?**

1. Get the logo in SVG, PSD or PNG file from the designer. SVG files are better because they are vector files that you can open it with free software like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). Change whatever you like and export it to the PNG.
2. If your logo is a text like what you have here, Search font by image and recreate it with Inkscape. The logo you mentioned here seems to be two fonts. `Clinica Pro` and `Sixta`. and both of them are not free font.
3. You can remove the background using Gimp, `Layer > Color to Transparency > Color to Alpha`, and select background color.

Useful links:

[Changing Background Color](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_1/)

[Making the background of an image transparent in Gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5446)

Anyway, I did remove the background from that logo for you (Transparent Background):

[image: Transparent]